# My js code doesn't show any definition when hover or press ctrl+k or ctrl+space

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, definition

My question simply is:
I can't show any definition when hover on my specially my javaScript code
even by hovering or pressing ctrl+k or ctrl+space
I tried my ways but I can't reach this point

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thanks a lot  I'm going to read and apply the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Installing the [Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode) extension will fix that.

But even with that installed, since JavaScript is a loosely typed language, things like variables will just show `any` when you hover over them.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) removed this issue for me.